# Show/Hide div based on data attributes value separated by comma in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have page that is showing Products list and Category filter. Product can have multiple categories.

HTML content be like

```
/*Product List */
      <div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,5"> Product 1 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3"> Product 2 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,5,4"> Product 3 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3,5"> Product 4 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,2,3,4,5"> Product 5 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="2"> Product 6 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3,4"> Product 7 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="5,1"> Product 8 </div>
        </div>

   /*Filter for category */
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="1"> Category 1 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[] "value="2"> Category 2 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="3"> Category 3 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="4"> Category 4 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="5"> Category 5 </br>
```

On Category select if I select Category 1 and 5  then its showing only **Product 1** but it should show all product those have category 1 or category 5

This code is working like AND condition, how to apply for OR  condition. so if 3 categories selected then show all products those have selected category.

```
$('.box').hide();
$('[data-category="1"],[data-category="5"]').show();
```

Comment: CSS selectors won't understand a comma separated list, you would be better using a filter.. https://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deal with your problem statement in simple steps like this.

**Step 1**: Apply `change` event to checkboxes. Check if the checkbox is checked and store checked checkboxes id into `selected_products` variable.

**Step 2**: Loop on each Products list and see if it is present in the `selected_products` array by splitting its `data-category` attribute. And show/hide accordingly.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){  
  var selected_products = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    if (this.checked){
      selected_products.push($(this).attr('value'));      
    }
  });
  $('.box').hide();
  selected_products.filter(function(item){
    $('.box').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('data-category').split(',').indexOf(item) > -1){
      $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,5"> Product 1 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3"> Product 2 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,5,4"> Product 3 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3,5"> Product 4 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,2,3,4,5"> Product 5 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="2"> Product 6 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3,4"> Product 7 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="5,1"> Product 8 </div>
        </div>
        
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="1"> Category 1 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[] "value="2"> Category 2 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="3"> Category 3 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="4"> Category 4 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="5"> Category 5 </br>
```

Comment: OK this answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
// this variable stores the categories to be displayed
var displayedCategories = []

// this function updates the products displayed based upon the previous variable
function updateDisplayed() {
  $('.box').each(function(i) {
    var box = $(this)
    var cats = [...box.attr('data-category')]
    box.hide()
    displayedCategories.forEach(function(category){
      if (cats.indexOf(category) >= 0) { box.show() }
    })
  })
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  // everytime you check or uncheck a box
  $('input[name="categories"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      // if the box is checked, you add to the array of displayables
      displayedCategories.push($(this).val())
    }
    else {
      // if not, you remove
      displayedCategories = displayedCategories.filter(x => x!= $(this).val())
    }
    
    // you update the displayed products
    updateDisplayed()
    
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,5"> Product 1 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3"> Product 2 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,5,4"> Product 3 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3,5"> Product 4 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="1,2,3,4,5"> Product 5 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="2"> Product 6 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="3,4"> Product 7 </div>
            <div class="box" data-category="5,1"> Product 8 </div>
        </div>


        <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="1"> Category 1 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="2"> Category 2 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="3"> Category 3 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="4"> Category 4 </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="5"> Category 5 </br>
```